# Write Unit Test in PersonServiceTest with using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Please help me, write Unit Test in PersonServiceTest using Mockito to mock `PersonDao` object in `PersonService`.

I'm tried to using when.then method but i had no ideal how to use

**PersonService class snippet**

```
public PersonService(PersonDao personDao) {
    m_PersonDao = personDao;
}
public List<Person> getAll() {
    return m_PersonDao.getAll();
}
public void save(Person p) {
    if (!m_PersonDao.isExistingPerson(p)) {
        m_PersonDao.save(p);
    }
}
public Person getByName(String name) {
    return m_PersonDao.getByName(name);
}
public Person getByBirthYear(Integer year) {
    return m_PersonDao.getByBirthYear(year);
}
```

**PersonServiceTest class snippet**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testPersonService() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testGetAll() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testSave() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testGetByName() {
    PersonDao personDao = Mockito.mock(PersonDao.class);

    Mockito.when(personDao.getByName("john")).thenReturn(new Person("John Thomspon", 1856);

    Person p = personDao.getByName("john");

    assert (p.getName().equals("John Thomspon"));
    //create mock objects: & create Instantiates the class under test using the created mock
}

@Test
public void testGetByBirthYear() {
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: You should check a tutorial on Mocks, I think that would be more helpfull than a short answer here.

Comment: except some minor comments your code is perfectly valid. Can you explain what is the issue? Some error?

Comment: it might be some issue in Person class

Comment: i have no idea how to write test save method in this case